# mysql query with count

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm running into my own limits of MySQL query skills, so I hope some SQL guru can help out on this one. I have 2 tables:

```
Table "comments" 
comment_ID    | comment_post_ID
     120      |    620
     121      |    620
     122      |    620
```

```
   Table "comments_like"
like_ID     |  comment_ID
    1       |   120
    2       |   120
```

I will result the numbers of comment that have a like group by comment_post_ID:

```
COUNT(comments in comments like) | comment_post_ID
      1                          |     620
```

Comment: How does one get a count of 1 given your example data?

Comment: because field "comment_ID" is get DISTINCT in comments_like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query give the post_id and the no of like for its comment in comment_like table

```
 SELECT comment_post_ID, count(like_ID)
 from (select distinct comment_post_ID,like_ID 
       from comments_like cl , comments c
 where cl.comment_ID= c.comment_ID ) as iq
 group by comment_post_ID
```

Comment: sorry but comments_like not have comments_post_id

Comment: I would know the number of comments that inside into comments_like (not duplicate), however, grouped by the comment_post_id

Comment: try now. This query will give post for which there is entry in comment_like table.

Comment: the new query return the postID that have a comments like, but i have need of the number of comments

Comment: almost perfect, must be return the number of comments and not comment like number

Comment: Excellent question.  The correct syntax is:  "from comments_like cl JOIN comments c ON cl.comment_ID = c.comment_ID".

Comment: hmmm...you mean the standard syntax...may be i am too old to change now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess a subquery is the easiest here:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(like_ID) FROM `comments_like` cl WHERE cl.comment_ID=c.comment_ID) AS comments_in_comments_like, c.comment_post_ID FROM `comments` c
```

This will produce count of 2 though for likes since comment id 120 has 2 likes in your example

Answer (score 0):

```
select cmtLike.like_ID, commnts.comment_post_ID
from comments_like cmtLike left join comments commnts on cmtLike.comment_ID = commnts.comment_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count each comment listed in `comments_like` just once, then:

```
select comment_post_ID, count(distinct cl.comment_ID) 
from comments c, comments_like cl 
where c.comment_id = cl.comment_id 
group by comment_post_ID
```